# IPhone SDK, EXC_BAD_ACCESS Changing image?

Tags: iphone, sdk, exc-bad-access

I have my code and i recieve the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when it is suppose to change... any ideas:

```
-(void) updatePlay {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bursttt" ofType:@"png"]];

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(pinend.frame, balloonbit1.frame)){
        [maintimer invalidate];
        accelManeger.delegate = nil;
        ball.image = img;
        [UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        ball.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
        [UIImageView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your timer is the problem. You're invalidating it, but not nil'ing it out, so if this code runs more than once without reseting the timer, it'll crash.

Comment: Ahh, i didn't think of that. Cheers mate works perfectly now.